# How do I fix this error when installing GHC with ghcup?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghcup

I'm trying to install GHC with ghcup on an windows laptop running an Ubuntu subsystem. I keep getting the same error and I don't even really know what is going wrong. Here are the error messages:

```
[ Info  ] verifying digest of: ghc-8.10.7-x86_64-fedora27-linux.tar.xz
[ Info  ] Unpacking: ghc-8.10.7-x86_64-fedora27-linux.tar.xz to /tmp/ghcup-61d1fb5776edc19e
[ Info  ] Installing GHC (this may take a while)
[ ghc-make ] # on Win64, "install -s" calls a strip that doesn't understand 64bit binaries.
[ ghc-make ] # For some reason, this means the DLLs end up non-executable, which means
[ ghc-make ] "utils/ghc-cabal/dist-install/build/tmp/ghc-cabal-bindist" copy compiler stage2 "strip" '' '/home/levi...
i...         Installing library in /home/levi/.ghcup/ghc/8.10.7/lib/ghc-8.10.7/ghc-8.10.7
i...         "/home/levi/.ghcup/ghc/8.10.7/lib/ghc-8.10.7/bin/ghc-pkg" --force --global-package-db "/home/levi/.gh...
[ ghc-make ] ghc-pkg: Couldn't open database /home/levi/.ghcup/ghc/8.10.7/lib/ghc-8.10.7/package.conf.d for modific...
i...         make[1]: *** [ghc.mk:985: install_packages] Error 1
             make: *** [Makefile:51: install] Error 2
[ Error ] BuildFailed failed in dir "/tmp/ghcup-61d1fb5776edc19e": Process "make" with arguments ["install"] failed with exit code 2.
[ ...   ]     Check the logs at /home/levi/.ghcup/logs and the build directory /tmp/ghcup-61d1fb5776edc19e for more clues.
[ ...   ]     Make sure to clean up /tmp/ghcup-61d1fb5776edc19e afterwards.
"_eghcup --cache install ghc recommended" failed!
levi@LAPTOP-BBDADJ2R:~$
```

Any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: What does the log shows (/home/levi/.ghcup/logs)?

Comment: in /.ghcup/logs there are 3 logs: ghc-configure.log,  ghc-make.log and ghcup.log. config log shows nothing out the ordinary  ending in https://gyazo.com/6e6bbe16118dcb11e15f83051b62e6d4,  the make log shows a few warnings https://gyazo.com/0bb41867757b81603facec27737e8888 https://gyazo.com/bb21cba484d51bc1131df7006742e744 then ends in the error messages https://gyazo.com/7e44e24f1dbecb7cb422a476bc3ecae5.

Comment: ghcup.log just shows the same lines as above https://gyazo.com/09904853880003c65118e0c0a89a5ee9

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Judging by this issue on the ghcup repo](https://gitlab.haskell.org/haskell/ghcup-hs/-/issues/117) (it cites the same error as yours), you are using WSL 1, which is not supported. You have to upgrade to WSL 2.

Comment: Oh boy this sent me through a rabbit hole, You're correct Ubuntu was still running in WSL version 1. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get install build-essential curl libffi-dev libffi7 libgmp-dev libgmp10 libncurses-dev libncurses5 libtinfo5 -y
```

Comment: Please add some documentation/references to understand what this is doing and why.

Answer (score 0):

1. open you home-> on rifgt side menu select " show hidden files"
2. You will able to see .ghcup folder
3. open .ghcup->cache
4. crate a file named ghcup-0.0.7.yaml
5. paste with
   lobalTools:
   ShimGen:
   dlUri: [https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghcup/shimgen/shim-2.exe](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghcup/shimgen/shim-2.exe)
   dlHash: 7c55e201f71860c5babea886007c8fa44b861abf50d1c07e5677eb0bda387a70
   toolRequirements:
   GHC:
   unknown_version:
   Linux_Debian:
   unknown_versioning:
   distroPKGs:
   - build-essential
   - curl
   - libffi-dev
   - libffi6
   - libgmp-dev
   - libgmp10
   - libncurses-dev
   - libncurses5
   - libtinfo5
   notes: ''
   ">= 11":
   distroPKGs:
   - build-essential
   - curl
   - libffi-dev
   - libffi7
   - libgmp-dev
   - libgmp10
   - libncurses-dev
   - libncurses5
   - libtinfo5
   notes: ''

Answer (score 0):

Write this on your terminal:

```bash
sudo apt-get install gcc
```